# Maximum Contiguous Sum in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I was reading [this](http://blog.anudeep2011.com/heavy-light-decomposition/) blog on Heavy light Decomposition and got confused with this statement:

> If a balanced binary tree with N nodes is given, then many queries can be done with O( log N ) complexity. Distance of a path, Maximum/Minimum in a path, ***Maximum contiguous sum*** etc etc.

I know it can be done in O(n) time using Kadane's Algorithm but,

**How would you find Maximum Contiguous sum in O(log n) time ?**

Comment: How do you define maximum contiguous sum? I can think of several definitions, and some of them are trivial in logarithmic time

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to adapt Kadane to a segment tree setting, which allows its inclusion in many data structures (see, e.g., [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21171144/2144669); I should have a proper citation, but it might be folklore).

That being said, the reason that maximum contiguous sum on a path is claimed O(log n) is for the trivial reason that every simple path in a balanced binary tree has length O(log n).

Comment: How do you define the maximum contiguous sum?

Comment: @AmiTavory On a specified path? Same as for a sequence.

Comment: @David Eisentat Thanks, but I'm still not getting it. How could I adapt Kadane's algorithm to a segment tree setting to get max contiguous sum in O(logn) time. Can you help with a bit of pseudo code.